# MVCContrib Partially Trusted Assembly Security Error on Deployment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor, mvccontrib

I am implementing MVCContrib's Castle ControllerFactory in my application. It seems to work great on my local machine but it is throwing SecurityExceptions at my web server (MS Server 2008).

```
 [SecurityException: That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers.]
   MvcContrib.Castle.WindsorExtensions.RegisterControllers(IWindsorContainer container, Type[] controllerTypes) +0
   MvcContrib.Castle.WindsorExtensions.RegisterControllers(IWindsorContainer container, Assembly[] assemblies) +36
   InteractiveToolsBuilder.MvcApplication.IntializeControllers() in C:\Dev\Team Interactive Tools\trunk\Infrastructure\Manufacturing\InteractiveToolsBuilder\Global.asax.cs:58
   InteractiveToolsBuilder.MvcApplication.Application_Start() in C:\Dev\Team Interactive Tools\trunk\Infrastructure\Manufacturing\InteractiveToolsBuilder\Global.asax.cs:64
```

I have added the following trust level in the web.config even though it appears that the web server is running with with "Full" level of trust.

Can someone tell me how to overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message was misleading. The problem was due to the fact that the assemblies where "blocked" after downloading them from the web.

Right Click each assembly and click, "unblock".